# Оформление блоков в CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid

В данный момент осваиваю CSS Grid и во время верстки столкнулся с проблемой: не понимаю, как можно "оформить" блок созданный с помощью грида. Т.е, к примеру, добавить в него еще один div, чтобы создать еще один блок внутри. Когда пытаюсь провернуть подобное, все столбцы улетают на орбиту. Помогите понять, пожалуйста, каким образом можно добавить оформление к подобным блокам. Желаемый результат (примерный) прикрепил в виде изображения.

[image: Примерный результат]

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  background: #232323;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #343434;
}

.window {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.bottom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #5539c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="window"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="window"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="window"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо. Не понимаю, почему у меня с подобным кодом все улетало.